# ubuntu 14.04LTS apache2 pretty url's not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

I've been beating my head against this wall for a while without success. I've done numerous searches and tried to implement all of the suggestions but still no joy. I would really appreciate any suggestions on why my set up is not working.

We've just setup server with Ubuntu 14.04LTS with LAMP environment and ever since I've been trying to make it work with a test site, which works perfectly fine on my local XAMPP setup.

Here is what my set up looks like:

enabled mod_rewrite with a2enmode rewrite

updated /etc/apache2.conf file to allow Override

```
<Directory /var/www/>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

setup new vhost in /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.dev.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.dev/public_html
    ServerName example.dev
    ServerAlias www.example.dev
    <Directory /var/www/example.dev/public_html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

enable virtual host with a2ensite example.dev.conf

copied .htaccess file from my local environment to /var/www/example.dev/public_html directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ [NC,L]
</IfModule>
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

finally restarted apache with apache2 reload

and still when I try to go to secondary pages I end up on the 404 page.

My site set up is:

```
example.dev/index.php
    subdirectory
        file1.php
        file2.php
etc.
```

and the links are example.dev/subdirectory/file1.php

If any one have any suggestions on how to make this work I'd be grateful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rule is missing target URL, use it as:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion and still no joy. I am still send to 404 page.

Comment: It's active, it generates 500 error when I put nonsense in it and ErrorDocument works just fine, since that's where it send me to. As well when I add .php to the end of the filename it works. This got me totaly baffled.

Comment: So this works: example.dev/subdirectory/file1.php  but this goes to 404 example.dev/subdirectory/file1

Comment: Thank you, your updated rule did the trick. The problem was this rewrite condition: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/.php !-f once I've updated it to this RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f everything worked.